# MS Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm fairly new here and i would like to use help of all excel experts here. So I've run into a problem at work. Situation is I have a table:

Row labels: Course names

columns labels: Job positions and further sub divided into new and Existing employees.

And cell values contains "Yes" for each column and row based on if that job description requires that course, there are more than one courses for each job description.

So I want make a another table by getting a values out of above table basis of "Yes", and I want to list the courses by job description.

For Example: job Description Courses Clerk courseA Clerk courseB Clerk courseC

I have been trying index and match function to get values but not getting any success. Please take a look at the pic below.

[image]

The result that I want:

[image]

Comment: What did you try

Comment: I'm trying a combination of index and match functions but not quite getting there.

Comment: without knowing the exact cell/sheet location of your 1st table.. I'll be quite hard to pinpoint an exact solution.. Sharing a sample file for would help. || Btw it is not impossible.. just need to do a countif  for the "yes" then use index match to load the 1st, 2nd, 3rd match from the 1st table into the second table.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply transposing the table, aren't you? Count the number or rows and columns in the first screenshot, then select a range that is as many columns wide as there are rows in the first table, and as many rows high as there are columns in the first table.

Enter the formula (adjust to your range, of course)

```
=TRANSPOSE($A$1:$H$7)
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, since this is an array formula.

Format the result to hide zero values.

Now, when the data in the first table is changed, the values in the second table are updated, too.

[image]

Comment: Not Really i wanted a course names in front of each description on based of "yes" Value. It wasn't a simple transpose. i eventually figured it out using ArrayFormula with offset, index, sumproducts ets. However, Many Thanks for taking a time out to solve my question.